# Managing Themes with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a dating site. The website will have multiple front end themes. I want to follow good practice when setting up the structure of the project. I have posted an image of how the structure will look like. Multiple front end themes in the themes folder containing all the images, css, etc related to that theme in the folder.

Am I on the right track here? How can I tell Spring which theme I want loaded?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Sitemesh to change theme depends on your URL pattern

http://codesilo.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/spring-mvc-with-sitemesh-3/